# How can I find the equation of perpendicular distance from an ellipse to a given line?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

There is ellipse whose center is origin and semi-axis are $a$ ($x$-axis) and $b$ ($y$-axis) respectively.

And there is line $L$ that passes through the origin and make angle $k$ with length of $2a$.

How can I find the perpendicular distance from point in ellipse to line L?

I only know $x=a\cos(k)$ and $y=b\sin(k)$

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea; let me know what you think.

Define the radial vector to the point in question $\mathbf V = <a\cos \theta , b\sin \theta >$ where $\theta$ is the angle swept out by the radial vector from the positive x axis.We're looking for the component of V perpendicular to the line. [image: Ellipse Diagram]

The magnitude of $\mathbf V$ is $\sqrt {a^2\cos^2 \theta + b^2\sin^2 \theta }$. Now define the angle between the line and the radial vector to be $\phi = \theta - k$. The component of V perpendicular to the line will be $\|\mathbf V \| \sin\phi$, or here $\sqrt {a^2\cos^2 \theta + b^2\sin^2 \theta } \sin\phi$, which will give you the distance from the point to the line. So I guess as long as you know the angle swept out to the point you're set.